# this.model.destroy() in backbone.js returns object has no method destroy

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to destroy a model (both in a collection and on my server), and from what I understand, backbone.js should pass the model.id and a DELETE request to my server if I call

```
this.model.destroy();
```

when I view `console.log(this.model);`, the console shows my model with this structure.

```
d
_callbacks: Object
_changed: false
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
cid: "c2"
collection: d
id: 13
__proto__: o
```

rails returns a 404 error, and when I output the response from backbone destroy function, I get

```
Object
abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
always: function (){return b.done.apply(b,arguments).fail.apply(this,arguments)}
complete: function (){if(!d){var c=arguments,g,h,i,j,k;b&&(k=b,b=0);for(g=0,h=c.length;g↵↵↵  ↵  Action Controller: Exception caught↵  ↵    body { background-color: #fff; color: #333; }↵↵    body, p, ol, ul, td {↵      font-family: helvetica, verdana, arial, sans-serif;↵      font-size:   13px;↵      line-height: 18px;↵    }↵↵    pre {↵      background-color: #eee;↵      padding: 10px;↵      font-size: 11px;↵    }↵↵    a { color: #000; }↵    a:visited { color: #666; }↵    a:hover { color: #fff; background-color:#000; }↵  ↵↵↵↵Routing Error↵No route matches [DELETE] "/menu_dishes"
```

↵↵↵↵↵↵"
setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
status: 404
statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(s

Any idea on how I should be deleting my model?
I don't see anything in the documentation about how I can pass the model id through to rails, as I think that is what is missing.

Comment: this.destroy() doesn't work because you are in a view, there's no "destroy()" on a view. this.model.destroy() would be the correct way (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-destroy) though you should give us the content (console.log(this.model)), that would help. And use a success/error callback in your call to this.model.destroy(), so you have more info on what happens.

Comment: And what routes are defined on your server? I don't know Ruby on Rails that much, but I *think* it uses a "_method" field to simulate "delete" and "put" http requests, right? Backbone supports this using `Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;`. Maybe worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default Backbone sync, then the url used for a model is calculated by this method (from Backbone source):

```
url: function() {
  var base = getValue(this.collection, 'url') || getValue(this, 'urlRoot') || urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
}
```

You are getting "/menu_dishes" when you think you should be getting "/menu_dishes/the_id", right?

You can add a breakpoint to Backbone.sync and step through the above code.  Maybe the id is not set right?  I am just guessing at this point, but by default Backbone is expecting the id attribute to be 'id', and maybe that is not the name of your id attribute (maybe it is 'dishId' or something?).

If that is the case, check out the Backbone source:

```
idAttribute: 'id'
```

Maybe you need to override that in your model.

Comment: interesting paul, I added a `console.log(this)` to the url function, but that doesn't get triggered at all with destroy. I guess maybe I'm not using sync, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: ignore that last comment, apparently there is no way to NOT use sync with destroy. The name of the id attribute is id, that is visible in the console log of the model `id: 13`

Comment: Put a breakpoint in sync(), or higher up in model.destroy() which calls sync. Step through the code and see what is happening. You should be able to see the url it is using when it sends the DELETE.